# Create simple jquery form with textarea, php and flat file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is a simple form for collecting names and comments, saving them in a flat file, and producing an html table to display the data.

I would like use jquery so that updates will display without reloading the page.

All of the explanations I've seen are over-my-head.  Should an amature be trying this ?  I can live with the page re-loads if I have to, but I'd rather not.

Any advice appreciated.

Here's the page I use now, with a file called 'messages.dat' :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['mssg'] > "") {
$mssg = $_POST['mssg'];
$del = "\t";
    $lines[0] = $_POST['username'];
$lines[1] = $_POST['mssg'];
$lines[1] = nl2br($lines[1]);
$lines[1] = str_replace("\r", "", $lines[1]);
$lines[1] = str_replace("\n", "", $lines[1]);
$file = fopen("messages.dat", "a");
$lines = implode($del, $lines) . "\r\n";
fwrite($file, $lines);
fclose($file);
}


?>
<html>
<head>

<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Blech</title>

</head>

<body>

<form name = "my_form"
id = "my_form" method  = "post" action="<?phpecho$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<label>Enter your name</label>
<br>
<input type = "text" name = "username">
<br>
<label>Enter mssg here</label>
<br>
<textarea name = "mssg" id = "mssg" cols = "40" rows = "4"></textarea>
<br>
<button name = "submit" id = "submit" value="submit" />submit</button>
</form>

<div id = "put_here">  <!--   THIS DIV DISPLAYS THE UPDATED CONTENT    -->
<?php
$board_content = "";
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("messages.dat", "r")) !== FALSE) {

$board_content = '<table border="1"><tr><th>Name</th><th>Message</th></tr>';

while (($lines = fgetcsv($handle, 100, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($lines);

$board_content .= '<tr>';

for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           if(empty($lines[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $lines[$c];
        }
**strong text**$board_content .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
}
$board_content .= '</tr>';
$row++;
}
fclose($handle);
echo $board_content . '</table><br>';
}

?>
</div>
<script>
//  ALWAYS GOTTA HAVE THIS CONTAINER:   $(document).ready(function(){
//   ENDS THE 'READY' CONTAINER:                            });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about storing the data in more structured json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the settings in json format if I had to use text.

Something like this could do the trick.

```
<?
    $file = 'messages.json';
    touch($file);       //create file if not exist
    $messages = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);
    if(empty($messages)){
        $messages = array();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['mssg'])) {  //save settings
        $messages[] = $_POST; //remember to sanitize
        file_put_contents($file,json_encode($messages));
        exit;
    }elseif(isset($_POST['read'])&&$_POST['read']=='messages'){
        echo json_encode($messages);
        exit;
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="my_form" method="post" action="">
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <br>
        <label>Enter mssg here</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="mssg" id="mssg" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />submit</button>
    </form>

    <div id="put_here">
        <table border="1" id="put_here_table">
        <!--messages will be added here-->
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>
        $("#my_form").submit(function(e){  //handle the form submission
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "./thisfile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function(response){
                    $("#put_here_table").append('<tr><td>'+$("#username").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#mssg").val()+'</td></tr>');
                    $("#mssg").val("");//clear the text box
                }
            });
        });
        $.ajax({  //load the messages
            dataType: "json",
            url: "./thisfile.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"read":"messages"},
            success: function(messages){
                if(messages.length){
                    $("#put_here_table").append('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Message</th></tr>');
                    $.each(messages,function(i,msg){
                        $("#put_here_table").append('<tr><td>'+msg['username']+'</td><td>'+msg['mssg']+'</td></tr>');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This page doesn't function.  I wrapped the script in a $(document).ready(function() container and still no go.  Perhaps hobbyists like me should stay away from Ajax.

Comment: Name the php file `thisfile.php`.

Comment: YES.  That made the difference.  I need to spend some hours with this.  Hope people plus this post so it gets found by others.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

change your button type submit to button.

```
<button type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />submit</button>
```